# How to get the value of radio button inside a modal box on a loop in laravel using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to get the value of radio button acceptTechnical. The radio button is inside a modal box which is inside a table in laravel but I keep getting the first value of the radio button instead of the particular one selected.

The value of the table is a loop.

Here is the my blade

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($service as $row)
        @if($row->full_name != "")
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="single-applicants-card">
                    <div class="image">
                        @if(!empty($row->profile_image))
                            <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$row->profile_image)}}" alt="image">
                        @else
                            <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('icon_02.jpeg')}}" alt="image"></a>
                        @endif

                    </div>

                    <div class="content" style="flex-wrap: wrap">

                        @if(empty($row->identity))
                            <h3>
                                <a href="#">{{$row->full_name}}</a>
                            </h3>
                        @else
                            <h3>
                                <a href="{{url('user/'.$row->identity)}}" target="_blank">{{$row->full_name}}</a>
                            </h3>
                            <h6>
                                {{ ucfirst($row->availability) }}
                            </h6>
                            <span>Status:</span>
                            <span style="font-weight: 600; color: black">
                                @if($row->approved == 0)
                                    Pending
                                @elseif($row->approved == 1)
                                    Screened
                                @elseif($row->approved == 2)
                                    Rejected
                                @elseif($row->approved == 4)
                                    Job Completed
                                @else
                                    Accepted
                                @endif
                            </span>
                            <div style="font-size: 14px">
                                {{ \App\Models\EmployerJobs::where("id", $row->job_id)->value("job_title")}}
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-size: 14px">
                                {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->updated_at)->format("d M, Y")}}
                            </div>
                            @endif

                        <ul class="job-info">
                            <li><i class="ri-phone-fill"></i> {{$row->phone}}</li>
                            <li><i class="ri-time-line"></i> {{$row->work_experience}} years</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="applicants-footer">
                            <ul class="option-list">
                                @if(isset($row->user_id))
                                    <?php $sam = \App\Models\User::where("id", \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)->value("is_admin") == 1 ? $row->identity :$row->applicant_identity; ?>
                                    <li><a target="_blank" href="{{ url("/user/". $sam )}}" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-color: #ffa836 !important;" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="View Profile" type="button">View</a></li>
                                @endif
                                @if(\App\Models\User::where("id", \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)->value("is_admin") == 1)
                                    @if(isset($row->user_id))
                                        <li><a href="{{ route("admin.application.approve",["job_id" => $row->job_id, "user_id" => $row->user_id, "employer_id" => $row->employer_id]) }}" class="option-btn d-inline-block" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Assign Candidate" type="button"><i class="ri-todo-fill"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('job/'. \App\Models\EmployerJobs::where("id", $row->job_id)->value("url")) }}" class="option-btn d-inline-block" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="View Job" type="button"><i class="ri-arrow-go-forward-fill"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{  route("admin.application.reject-application",["job_id" => $row->job_id, "user_id" => $row->user_id, "employer_id" => $row->employer_id]) }}" class="option-btn d-inline-block" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Reject Application" type="button"><i class="ri-close-line"></i></a></li>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                @if(\App\Models\User::where("id", \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)->value("is_admin") == 2)
                                    @if(isset($row->user_id))
                                        <li>
                                            <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RejectModal{{ $row->identity }}" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-color: #ffa836 !important;" type="button">Reject</button>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#AcceptModal{{ $row->identity }}"  class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-color: #ffa836 !important;" data-bs-placement="top" type="button">Accept</button>
                                        </li>

                                    @endif
                                @endif

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="AcceptModal{{ $row->identity }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Kindly endorse this Candidate</h5>
                                <span>Rate this candidate's skills from 1-10</span>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>

                        </div>
                        <form action="{{ route("employer.candidate.approved") }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="identity{{ $row->identity}}" value="{{ $row->identity }}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="job_id" id="id" value="{{ $row->job_id }}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="employer_id" id="id" value="{{ $row->employer_id }}" />
```

The is the radio button I am trying to get its value

```
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" value="{{ $row->identity }}" type="radio" name="acceptTechnical"  id="accept{{$row->identity}}">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                            Technical Skills
                                        </label>
                                        <div id="accept-wait">Please wait...</div>
                                        <div id="acceptSkills{{ $row->identity }}"></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" id="ok" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This is my jquery

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="acceptTechnical"]').prop('checked', false);
         $('input[type=radio][name=acceptTechnical]').change(function() {
            const id =  $(this).val()
            let skills = [];
            let scores = ""
            $("div#accept-wait").css("display", "block")
            axios.get('/employer/get-user-tech-skills?id=' + id )
                .then(function (response) {
                    $("#acceptSkills" + id).html(response.data)
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    $("#acceptSkills" + id).html("")
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .finally(function () {
                    // always executed
                    $("div#accept-wait").css("display", "none")

                });
        });


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, replace this line

```
const id =  $(this).val();
```

By this line

```
const id = $('input[type=radio][name=acceptTechnical]:checked').val();
```